# print out last character after regex

Tags: javascript, regex

> I want to print following character after matched character(ad) but i don't know how to call it as an argument, any help ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {
  
  var text2 = $(this).val();
  
  text2 = text2.replace(/ad(?=a|ı|o|u|R|T|S|B|q|Y|L|Ğ|I|D)/g, "D$2");
  
  $("#ta_1").val(text2);
  
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
<textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28" ></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you go into depth a bit with what you are asking? What are you trying to do (be specific) and what isn't working?

Comment: an example would be helpful too. `"blue".replace(/ue/, "arg") #=> "blarg"`. do you want to print, `blarg`, `arg`, `ue` etc

Comment: @kirkpatt yes of course as an example,1) typed string: ada, target string(what i want):Da,,, 2) typed string:adS, target string: DS,,,etc etc..

Comment: @PhilVarg typed string:adT,  target string:DT,,,,typed string:adR,,,target string:DR,,,typed string:adu, target string:Du  etc  etc

Comment: I guess this should do `text2.replace(/ad([aıouRTSBqYLĞID])/,"D$1")`

Comment: @Redu thanks but it works only once right ? :/

Comment: For multiple matches just add g flag to the regex like `text2.replace(/ad([aıouRTSBqYLĞID])/g,"D$1")` then you should be all fine.

Comment: @Redu yep ! perfect ! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, and your code was pretty close to one of them; you just had to remove the `$1`.  Another solution would be to [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) rather than [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
"adoadR".replace(/ad(?=a|ı|o|u|R|T|S|B|q|Y|L|Ğ|I|D)/g, "D$1"); // #0: "D$1oD$1R"
"adoadR".replace(/ad(?=a|ı|o|u|R|T|S|B|q|Y|L|Ğ|I|D)/g, "D");   // #1: "DoDR"
"adoadR".replace(/ad(a|ı|o|u|R|T|S|B|q|Y|L|Ğ|I|D)/g, "D$1");   // #2: "DoDR"
```

To further optimize, you should also collapse that alternation into a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
"adoadR".replace(/ad(?=[aıouRTSBqYLĞID])/g, "D"); // #3: "DoDR"
"adoadR".replace(/ad([aıouRTSBqYLĞID])/g, "D$1"); // #4: "DoDR"
```

Since capturing is expensive, I'd recommend against it since you don't need it.

My #3 is the best solution.